# Soft reset of magnetometer in Android

Tags: android, magnetometer

I have noticed that by shaking or tapping the phone (an SE Xperia x10 mini) several times recalibrates the magnetometer. Is there any way of doing this software-wise in a more controlled way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. It seems some sort of "hardware reset": when the magnetometer has been confused by a magnetic field (a loudspeaker is usually enough) it requires physical movement in order to return to a "plain state".

Comment: Yes, that would be my guess as well. And I tested on a HTC Hero as well with similar result. Perhaps there is an event created that can be caught?

Comment: That's a good question. Maybe you can check for accuracy changing to/from SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE, but I think it is device-dependent.

Comment: Did not think of that! This will require some elaborate testing but might actually solve the problem in a quite elegant manner.

Comment: Just for the record - the accuracy does not appear to be affected unfortunately. And as there isn't anything showing on the debug output when this happens. The last remote possibility now seems to be to make a prediction from the data itself - perhaps together with the accelerometer when this event are to happen.

Comment: That's bad! On which device are you developing?

Comment: Primarily I use an Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 mini running Android 1.6